# How can SignalR Cors be configured for an ASPNETCore 2.1 application?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, cors, signalr

I am trying to configure CORS for my aspnetcore 2.1 application. I have followed the documentation closely. My Startup file has been configured as follows.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options => options
            .AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://sitetracker")
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSignalR(o => o.EnableDetailedErrors = true);
        services.AddDbContext<BiometricContext>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<BiometricsHub<User>>("/biometricshub");
        });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

I configured and angular project to start a hub connection and wait on a the server to push some information to the client.

```
    var port = 58422;
    this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(`http://localhost:${port}/BiometricsHub`)
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
        .build();

    this.connection.on("ReceiveActiveIdentities", (identities) => {
        debugger // Waiting here to receive data
    });

    this.connection.start().catch(err => {
        debugger // Error is "Error" with and error code of 0
        console.error(err.toString());
    });
```

An error is caused when the connection.start is called.

[image]

Since I couldn't figure out why the cors error was happening I wanted to know if the code was broken in some other way. I disabled the cors security in a browser session by executing the following line at the run menu.

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

Once CORS was disabled, the code would return the data in my client callback as expected. This leads me to believe everything outside of my CORS configuration is correct.

What is missing in my configuration? I can still not get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had tried this before in my many configurations. However, this seems not to be the case. Maybe at the time app.UseCors() followed app.UseMvc which apparently is a no-no.

```
builder.WithOrigins("http://sitetracker")
   .AllowAnyHeader()
   .AllowAnyMethod()
   .AllowCredentials();
```

The three following it allows need to be in place or more restricted versions which allow your particular actions or methods to be executed as needed.